# Comparing elements of list, how do I avoid duplicate comparisons?

Tags: c#, duplicates, compare, generic-list

In my app, I have a list of file paths like

```
private string[] listOfFiles = {
    "A.txt", "B.txt", "C.txt", "D.txt"
};
```

and I need to compare every single one of these files to all other files in the list, so the straightforward way would look like

```
A.txt - B.txt
A.txt - C.txt
A.txt - D.txt
B.txt - A.txt
B.txt - C.txt
B.txt - D.txt
```

...and so on.

As you can see, this is not optimal, since in this example, I am comparing A.txt to B.txt twice, wasting time and resources.

How do I avoid duplicate comparisons like this? I'm sure there's a simple way, but I'm not seeing it and my Google-fu is failing me.

Comment: Do you need to validate the content or just remove duplicate file paths?

Comment: I'm actually comparing images, which, with the amount of images I'm processing, can take ages, and even longer with all the duplicates. I just need to get rid of all the duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

With a double loop you can compare two filename only once like something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++){
          // comparison
    }
}
```